# imac 5.1 late 2006 ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac

I have an iMac 5,1 (late 2006 model 2.16GHz Intel Core 2 Duo running OS lion).

I've installed refind and I am trying to install ubuntu linux 14.04.3 LTS (32bit version) from my USB. This is the message that I receive after choosing the USB to boot from:

```
*Starting legacy loader
Using load options 'USB'
Error: Not Found returned from legacy loader
Error Not Found from LocateDevicePath
Error Not Found from LocateDevicePath
Error Not Found from LocateDevicePath
...
Error: Load Error while (re)opening our installation volume
The firmware refused to boot from the selecteed volume. Note that external hard drives are nt well supported by Apple's firmware for legacy OS booting.
Hit any key to continue
```

If I press any key, nothing happens, the image is frozen and I have to shut down my iMac by using the power button.

I have visited many sites so far but I haven't been able to find a solution although I have tried several of them. I've tried to install Ubuntu through live cd but I received a frozen black screen or another one with 2 boot cd options but I was not able to make a choice.

I've also tried the suggested method from the Ubuntu site for making a bootable USB or alternative ones that I found in the web but the problem remains.

Please note that I am a newbie and not familiar with what exactly I need to do in order to configure all necessary files for example through terminal commands but I am patient and eager to learn.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/276924/live-usb-instructions-for-mac-dont-work-for-12-10

Comment: Yes, I've read that post. However none of the solutions offered worked for me either.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a late 2006 iMac 5,1 Core 2 Duo and spent many hours trying to get Ubuntu installed as a full replacement for Lion without success.  The DVDs just wouldn't boot.  Instead I got asked to select a boot device 1 or 2  (don't remember the exact question), but my keyboard wouldn't work.

Tried USBs. Tried various boot loaders.  Tried bizarre tricks involving holding down the 1 key till you see a black screen, then quickly hitting Enter when the shade of black changes.  There's lots of good intentioned but useless advice out there, as the original poster said.  I was about to give up when I stumbled on this solution:

https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

which explains how to create a DVD image that boots perfectly on late 2006 macs.  Be sure to thank him if it works for you too!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have iMac 5,2 late 2006 with 64 bit Lubuntu 14.04 LTS. Solved with plop boot manager.

Get plop boot manager at [www.plop.at](http://www.plop.at) and burn the ISO. Boot from plop CD, and select boot from USB in plop menu. The Mac will boot by default after time out. Mouse and KB then work for install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot trouble trying to make a 2006 imac boot on a usb drive. The easiest way I found for me was to open it take the hard drive put it on another computer with a Bios (not an UEFI one) install linux and put back the hardrive in the mac.